# W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, dart-pub

The keyboard is not working properly.
It comes up when tapping the form field and goes down **very quickly.**
Doctor is fine.
ran flutter get pub
Did reinstall the app in the advice and reStart the notebook
But still the bug.....

**The problem started when I placed the focusNode.**
the @override Dispose() was unavailable - very strange.
I did the code without it.... and the problem with the keyboard started.
Then I rolled back to the point the code was working fine before - but the problem is still there ( strange)

**debug console message:**

W/FlutterEngine(29171): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@efebd17) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/libGLESv2(30653): DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.medicamento
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30653): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection

**Code File**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';

import '../providers/medicamento.dart';
import '../providers/medicamentos.dart';

class MedicamentoAddScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/medicamento-add';

  @override
  _MedicamentoAddScreenState createState() => _MedicamentoAddScreenState();
}

class _MedicamentoAddScreenState extends State<MedicamentoAddScreen> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //MUST BE PLACED HERE
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();// can not be placed here.
```

Comment: I think, the screen is rebuilding when tapping the text formfield. because I´m able to choose the dropdown menu and calendar -> the options selected stays. But, when I tap in the textFORMfield - the keyboard appears and disappears and the data selected previewsly - desappears ( the screen is rebuild).
The stack, also, pointed to that

Comment: Solved
Form global key in the build
I´ll comment in the code above.